# controller won't stay in sniff mode

Tags: bluetooth, bluez, hci

I'm using the bluez stack on linux and need to put a slave controller into sniff mode. I am able to initiate sniff mode by issuing the command with hcitool: `hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x02 0x0003 0x00 0x01 0x12 0x00 0x12 0x00 0x01 0x00 0x01 0x00`. The problem is that the slave always issues an exit sniff mode command immediately after I send any data on this socket. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can stop the controller from exiting sniff mode arbitrarily?

Comment: Thanks for the response, ukBaz. I’m actually not doing scanning, I’m trying to put an established connection into sniff mode which is a power saving mode like hold and park. I’ll have to look at the bluez API docs again, but I didn’t see a way to do this from that level of the stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with the default params for the linux bluetooth driver.

Answer (score -1):

Either device is allowed to exit sniff mode at any time. This is part of how classic Bluetooth is defined. I'm guessing that your target device's controller has a policy to automatically resume active mode at a certain data size payload.

If you want a persistent connection with sniff characteristics, I suggest implementing a low energy ACL.

Comment: You mean a BLE connection?

Comment: Is there a way to change the policy? Both devices are my own linux machines running the bluez stack.

Comment: Yes I do mean BLE, it sounds like what you're looking for. As for the controller policy, it doesn't seem like bluez has a specific mechanism for this. You would have to build a process to monitor the ACL mode change events and reset sniff mode as required.